# WD (Western Digital) Mybook appears and disappears

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, usb-3, hardware-detection

Don't know but maybe it's an odd problem,
Using **windows 8**, didn't have critical errors, sometime I got the blue screen on Win8,
after restarting it didn't show my **WD MyBook 2TB USB3 external drive**,
I was busy on my works, but tried another PC and it worked, tried Win7 on that PC and it was working ok,
Second time on Win7 tests again it's gone, maybe it will do the same process of `appearing and working and again disappearing`....

The status of the drive when it's visible shows it's **healthy** and working properly.

The last time on Win7 it was showing all the folders with files but inner folders all were empty!

The sizes were correct and it has about 2TB used( about 60 GB of it is free)
I have some important data on it,
but **looking to recovery software as the last option**,
I want to know when it seems to work somehow is there any tool that can fix this?
or any Western Digital additional tool to simply fix this crazy behavior?

Comment: Sounds like S.M.A.R.T data is failing you.  You take this behavior as a sign you need to replace the hdd.  If it is a failure there really isn't a fix that is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the bad news :D, so I have no options, and at the first possible time I should backup my data, If anyone found any better options please provide me

Comment: Any tools that might extend the lifespan of the drive, would mean you removing the drive, from the enclosure. Even those tools would not guarantee it would resolve this problem.  I suspect its the usb-to-sata controller within the enclosure itself.

Comment: thanks for the reply, don't know why that happens, It was working fine, now again I switched to the USB2 port and again it's working like nothing have happened, again don't know of the next restart, will it be there or no.